# First payment for reccuring payment on Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, recurring-billing

I'm currently setting a recurring paypal payment.
I'm not sure to understand when the first payment is done.
In my case, I want to first payment to be done when the user subscribe, and automaticaly renew after 3 month.
I'm not sure if the "**INITAMT**" parameter if the good way to do that.

Moreover, when I try to set the parameter "**INITAMT**" in sandbox, the résulting profile is always "**PengindProfile**"

Here is my parameters :

```
'METHOD' => 'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile',
'TOKEN' => $token,
'PAYERID' => $payerId,
'USER' => $user,
'SIGNATURE' => $signature,
'PWD' =>$password,
'VERSION' => 74.0,
'PROFILESTARTDATE' => gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"),
'DESC' => 'My subscription',
'BILLINGPERIOD' => 'Month',
'BILLINGFREQUENCY' => '3',
'AMT' => 10,
'CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',
'PAYERID' => XXX,
'MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS' => 3,
'INITAMT' => 10
```

And a finale question, how does the reccuring Payment works ? Paypal send the money on my account each 3 month ? It is possible to get a notification on a PHP serveur to update the subscription status ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely look into using the [PayPal PHP SDK](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/) instead of trying to use their REST API directly or via some minimal library. Their SDK provides much convenience working with the service and has plenty of use-case based examples including recurring billing and subscriptions.